# Encrypt by mcrypt and decrypt by openssl with mode CBC and cipher BLOWFISH

Tags: php, encryption, openssl, mcrypt

We have encrypted some data in mcrypt cipher `BLOWFISH` and mode is `CBC`
String encrypted in `php5.5` and need to decrypt this in `php7.1` (php version upgraded)

Following is our code to trying to decrypt mcrypt string using openssl

```
$data = "Lorem ipsum";
$key = "12345678";
$iv = "12345678";

$encrypted = mcrypt_encrypt(
    MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
echo $encrypted . PHP_EOL;

$decrypted = openssl_decrypt(
    $encrypted, "BF-CBC", $key,
    OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, $iv);

echo $decrypted;
```

Above code is not decrypting string.
Please suggest me any method to decrypt string

Comment: did you get any specific error?

Comment: It seems that the key size for `BF-CBC` is 16 bytes. Also, you'll have to unpad the decrypted data - just `rtrim` zero bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were missing one option on the `openssl` side: `OPENSSL_DONT_ZERO_PAD_KEY`.

If the length of the key given to `openssl_decrypt()` is shorter than the default key length for the cipher (Blowfish in this case) the PHP `openssl` glue code expands the key to that length by adding additional zeros. You can see it happen [here](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.2.10/ext/openssl/openssl.c#L6457). The `mcrypt` implementation does not do that key padding. The `openssl` default key length for Blowfish is 16 bytes, so if your key is shorter than 16 bytes, the keys for `mcrypt` and `openssl` will be different -- unless you use the `openssl` option to not do that padding of the key.

Verifying that this is indeed the case:

```
# bf.php
$data = "Lorem ipsum";
$key = "12345678";
$iv = "12345678";

$encrypted = mcrypt_encrypt(
    MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
#echo $encrypted . PHP_EOL;

$decrypted = openssl_decrypt(
    $encrypted, "BF-CBC", $key,
    OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING | OPENSSL_DONT_ZERO_PAD_KEY, $iv);

echo $decrypted . PHP_EOL;
```

and

```
$ php bf.php
Lorem ipsum
```

[This comment by t.m.adam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52387303/encrypt-by-mcrypt-and-decrypt-by-openssl-with-mode-cbc-and-cipher-blowfish/52397732#comment91720560_52387303) is relevant too, with regard to the zeroes at the end. Expanding on that suggestion:

```
var_dump($decrypted);
var_dump(rtrim($decrypted));
```

gives

```
string(16) "Lorem ipsum"
string(11) "Lorem ipsum"
```

You can not do `rtrim` for binary data of course, in that case you will have to remember or store what the size of your original plaintext was, or manually pad the data according to some useful padding schema as opposed to zero-padding. `mcrypt_encrypt()` does not seem capable of doing that.